# How can I select the Nth PreviousSibling in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager it's quite easy to use the element, element classes, element parent classes to fire tags. Unfortunately in this case I want to scrape an element which is only available in the same .

So, when people click on the link "delete" (class=deleteItem) I want to scrape the url_product_id (in bold).

I've tried so much but can't figure out how to achieve this. I hope somebody can help me out.

```
<td align="center">
   <span class="selquantity menosdis"></span>
   <span class="selquantity plus"></span>
   <input class="urlProductId" type="hidden" name="url_product_id" value="113293">
   <input class="urlQuantity" type="text" name="url_quantity" value="1" readonly="readonly">
   <br>
   <a style="cursor: pointer" class="deleteItem">delete</a>
</td>
```

Comment: it's all a tree. go up to the parent (td), then find elements with class `urlProductId` within that parent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to accomplish this within an event handler, you could use `parentNode` and `querySelector` to accomplish your goal:

```
var myClickHandler = function(event) {
   var productId = event.target.parentNode.querySelector('. urlProductId').value;
   // do stuff with productId
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('.deleteItem').on('click', function() {
   var productId = $(this).prev('.urlProductId').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery method (modify and test on your own), and you could do this in a GTM Custom Javascript variable:

```
function(){
   var ce = {{Click Element}}; // get the clicked element
   if ($(ce).length > 0){
      return $(ce).closest('td').find('.urlProductId').attr('name');
   }
   return undefined;
}
```

The premise here being that your elements are all nested under the `<td>` element, and all you're doing is taking the clicked element and scraping for the element you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Rob's answer, but also takes into account if code is moved around into additional divs, etc.. Since people update their UI all the time. This should be more sustainable as the product matures. Of course you'll want to watch the .closest() call if you ever change to something like BootStrap data tables.

```
$(".deleteItem").on("click", function() {
  var getClosestProdID = $(event.target).closest('td').find('.urlProductId');

  // Just for display of the value
  alert("Our closest selected value is: " + getClosestProdID.val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/probie/hLk45m9x/1/)